# Cannot get jQuery mouseover to work with Span

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
        $('.popUp').mouseover(function() {
            var divName = $(this).data("id");
            $('#' + divName).fadeIn();
        });

        $('.popUp').mouseout(function() {
            var className = $(this).data("id");
            $('#' + divName).fadeOut();
        });
```

It's supposed to show a pop-up near some text that gets hovered over.  The text to be shown is stored in hidden DIVs elsewhere on the page.  I pass the name of the DIV in via data-id="divname" in the SPAN tag.  Thing is, no matter what I do, jQuery won't react to the text.  Not on mouseover, hover, even click.  Nothing.  I tested it by placing an alert() in there just to see if would react, but it never does.

Here's an example of one of the SPANs:

```
I am <span class="popUp" data-id="s1"><u>employed</u>, volunteering</span>, or 
<span class="popUp" data-id="s2"><u>associated</u></span>
```

What am I doing wrong? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use it like `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`-> `mouseenter` instead of `mosueleave`

Comment: Have you put your code within document ready handler?

Comment: In the mouseout function, should `classname` be `divName`?

Comment: Change span tags to div tags and watch the diff. I bet this is a display issue. Also, you could try CSS, set the display value of the span tags to `inline-block`. Just give it a try. Spans are funny this way.

Comment: I switched to mouseenter/leave, chained them, set display to inline-block, switched to DIV.  No change.  Yes, it's in $(document).ready() :)

Comment: Is your console showing any errors? I created a fiddle you can play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/83uEs/

Comment: @RobG: MouseEnter and MouseLeave sounds better than mouseover and mouseout but regardless it should do something. Is your jQuery script reference pointing to a valid file location? Do you get any error in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to debug without more details.

```
 $(document).on("mouseover", ".popup", function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(id).fadeIn();
 }).on('mouseout', '.popup', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(id).fadeOut();   
 });
```

​

I also tried this

```
$(".popup").mouseover(function() {
var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(id).fadeIn();
 }).mouseout(function(){
var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(id).fadeOut();
 })
```

And it works. The problem is probably because .popup doesn't exist on dom ready (maybe it's being loaded from an AJAX request?). We can't be sure unless we see the full code. The code with $(document).on() should work a good 99% of the time (statistic pulled from thin-air)

Here is a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Pp9w/

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!  Now to figure out how to position the pop-up text near the specific SPAN.

Answer (score 3):

You have not posted the mark-up of the divs but assuming something similar to this:

```
I am <span class="popUp" data-id="s1"><u>employed</u>, volunteering</span>, or 
<span class="popUp" data-id="s2"><u>associated</u></span>

<div id="s1">The s1 div</div>
<div id="s2">The s2 div</div>
```

Ones the variable name was changed from `className` to `divName` it works fine.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TEb3G/) - Default, after variable name fix

As mentioned in a comment on the original code, make sure your script runs within a document ready block and make sure any jQuery references are there and valid.

In addition if you find animation to behave erratically when mousing over rather quickly between links you could update your code similar to this:

```
$('.popUp').mouseover(function() {
    var divName = $(this).data("id");
    $('#' + divName).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});

$('.popUp').mouseout(function() {
    var divName = $(this).data("id");
    $('#' + divName).hide();
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gf2K3/) - Alternate code using `stop()` and `hide()`

The only thing I added/changed (which you may not need at all) is `stop(true, true)` to stop previous animations if you mouseover rather quickly over the links back and forth.

Also, instead of `fadeOut()` `hide()` might work better, again due to possible clashes with animation when mousing over quickly between the links.

Those are just suggestions and may not apply directly to you scenario.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  Well, something else is up then because it doesn't work.  I guess I have to go back to the old way it was being done, using onmouseover in the tags themselves.  Ugh.  What a coding mess that was.

Answer (score 1):

I created A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PT2L3/1/) . and it working fine.

modified code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.popUp').mouseover(function() {
                var divName = $(this).data("id");
                $('#' + divName).fadeIn();
            });

    $('.popUp').mouseout(function() {
            var divName = $(this).data("id");
            $('#' + divName).fadeOut();
        });

​});
```

HTML:

`I am <span class="popUp" data-id="s1"><u>employed</u>, volunteering</span>, or  <span
 class="popUp" data-id="s2"><u>associated</u></span> <div id=s2 style='display:none'> text
 text text text text text text text text  </div> <div id=s1 style='display:none'> text text
 text text text text text text text  </div>` ​

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
$('.popUp').mouseover(function() {
   var divName = $(this).data("id");
    $('#' + divName).fadeIn();
});
$('.popUp').mouseout(function() {
    var className = $(this).data("id");
    $('#' + divName).fadeOut();
});
```

For the mouseout event, you use define *className* but you USE *divName*. Change *divName* to *className*.